# Ruby: How to get a list of keys to reach a leaf key in nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

```
h = {:c=>{:b=>"ss"}, :a=>{:e=>{:b=>"foo"}}, :x=>{:y=>{:z=>{:b=>"hai"}}}}
```

I need a method which will return all nested keys to reach a given leaf level key

for example,

```
h.paths_to(:b) => [[:c],[:a,:e],[:x,:y,:z]]
```

I know only the key name what I am looking for, which is ':b'. It may exist at any level in depth of this hash and at multiple places. The method should return all the paths (keys) to reach the given key in this nested hashes.

Note: the key will not be having another hash as value.

I tried several ways, could not identify a solution. Please help.

Comment: Try recursion using each sub-hash.

Comment: Is `h = {:c=>{:b=>"ss"}, :a=>{:e=>{:b=>"foo"}}, :x=>{:y=>{:z=>{:b=>"hai"}}}}` even a valid Ruby assignment? What's being assigned to `h`, a hash or an array?

Comment: @Cupcake, I don't understand your point, `h.is_a? Hash
 => true`.

Comment: Never mind, you guys are right, I got confused by all of the nested curly braces everywhere.

Comment: How is this hash created? If it's an intermediate format, then perhaps you should skip the creation of the hash altogether.

Comment: Suppose `h = {:b=>'ss', :c => {:b=>'tt'}, :d=>{:b=>{:e=>{:b=>'uu'}}}}`.  Would you want one of the following three results, or something else: 1) `[[], [:c], [:d]]`, 2) `[[], [:c], [:d], [:d,:e]]`, 3) `[[], [:c], [:d,:e]]`?  Interesting question.

Comment: This question has had an interesting history.  It almost immediately garnered three down votes and two votes to close.  As far as I could tell that was only because the asker had written `:C` rather than `:c`.  After he/she fixed that, one of the downvotes and both votes to close were retracted.  I thought it was obvious that it was just a typo, but if those who voted to close thought otherwise, or didn't know, why didn't they just leave a comment and give the asker some time to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built in method that can do this.

I would use recursion to walk through the Hash and build the array up manually.

```
class Hash
  def paths_to(search_key)
    results = []
    each do |key, value|
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        result = value.paths_to(search_key)
        unless result.empty?
          result.each do |keys|
            results << [key] + keys
          end
        end
      else
        # Leaf node
        if key == search_key
          results << []
        end
      end
    end
    results
  end
end

hash = {:c => {:b => "ss"}, :a => {:e => {:b => "foo"}}, :x => {:y => {:z => {:b => "hai"}}}}
puts hash.paths_to(:b).inspect
#=> [[:c], [:a, :e], [:x, :y, :z]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hash
  def paths_to key
    flat_map do |k, v|
      if v.kind_of?(Hash).!
      elsif v.key?(key) then [[k]]
      else v.paths_to(key).map{|a| a.unshift(k)}
      end
    end.compact
  end
end


{:c=>{:b=>"ss"}, :a=>{:e=>{:b=>"foo"}}, :x=>{:y=>{:z=>{:b=>"hai"}}}}.paths_to(:b)
# => [[:c], [:a, :e], [:x, :y, :z]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I left a comment on the question for clarification, using my second example below.  Here I'm assuming that the asker wants `path_to` to return the third possible result I mentioned.

```
class Hash
  def paths_to(key, keys_so_far = [], arr = [])
    each do |k,v|
      arr << keys_so_far if k == key
      v.paths_to(key, keys_so_far + [k], arr) if v.is_a? Hash
    end
  arr
  end
end

h = {:b=>"r",:c=>{:b=>"ss"},:a=>{:e=>{:b=>"foo"}},:x=>{:y=>{:z=>{:b=>"hai"}}}}
h.paths_to(:b) #=> [[], [:c], [:a, :e], [:x, :y, :z]] 

h = {:b=>"ss", :c=>{:b=>"tt"}, :d=>{:b=>{:e=>{:b=>"uu"}}}}
h.paths_to(:b) #=> [[], [:c], [:d], [:d, :b, :e]]
```

Comment: The OP notes "the key will not be having another hash as value", which means there is no need of considering such case.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa.  I'll leave it as is, as it still works in that case.